# How to insert text after point?

Tags: text-editing, point

I'd like to insert (programmatically) some text right after the point (without moving it).  I came up with this:

```
(save-excursion (insert "my text"))
```

It seems to work.  Is it a good way to do what I want?  E.g., are there situations where this could break?  (Other than those where `insert` would break anyway, like read-only buffers.)  Is it different from what would more experienced Elisp hackers do?

Comment: Yes. Not much more to say.

Comment: Thanks; I was a bit worried about e.g. some (strange?) situations when it wouldn't work etc.

Comment: You could rephrase the question in that case. But 99% of the time, `save-excursion` + `insert` is the way to go.

Comment: OK, I'll do it.  BTW: what is the 1%?

Comment: Weird modes with read-only overlays and that sort of thing. Nothing to worry about really.

Comment: @shosti could you make that an answer? Even a short answer is better than none.

Comment: Agreed.  Also, why don't you wrap my solution in a `defun`?  This would be more elegant, I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very common example of this behavior is `electric-pair-mode` in the Emacs standard library.  If you've never used this mode before, then (quoting from [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Matching.html)):

> Whenever you insert an opening delimiter, the matching closing delimiter is automatically inserted as well, leaving point between the two.

You can check out the code for `electric-pair-post-self-insert-function` to see how it accomplishes the insertion.  Spoiler:

```
(defun electric-pair-post-self-insert-function ()
  [lots of cond logic to decide if it's time to insert a matching closer]
      (save-excursion (insert closer)))))))
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that is the most idiomatic way of inserting text after point that I know of. `save-excursion` is very resilient to changes in the buffer, so it is the preferred way to do destructive editing. The only place you're likely to run into issues is where you would have issues with `insert` itself, such as buffers where some text is read-only.