# Inserting text after current point

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I've got a mild annoyance that I'm sure is fixable, but I'm not sure where to look. When using `org-ref-helm-insert-cite-link` to insert citations in my org documents, the citation is inserted at the current point. The problem is that if I've left insert mode, the current point is before the space, rather than after the space where I'd like the citation to go. I've read [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/how-to-insert-text-after-point), but it seems to be trying to do something different.

## Example

**Typed text**:

`These·steps·are·called·authentication·`

**After `org-ref-helm-insert-cite-link`**:

`These·steps·are·called·authenticationcite:Furnell2000·`

**Desired format**:

`These·steps·are·called·authentication·cite:Furnell2000`

Configuration: Spacemacs with vim style

Answer (score 2):

This can be disabled in Evil by customizing `evil-move-back-cursor` to `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

this is vi(m) style behaviour, where the point is moved back one char upon entering command state.  pressing`i` or doing a complex insert uses the current point, not the one where you left editing mode.  If you don't want this behaviour, try a) to find a variable which sets the according offset, or b) do not use evil (or any other vi emulation).